# Powershell Join-Path showing 2 dirs in result instead of 1 - accidental script/function output

Tags: powershell, return, output, return-value, multiple-return-values

I am constructing incremental directory structures, and for some reason `Join-Path` is showing 2 dirs. When I later join that with a file I'm sending to copy-item, it causes an error, as shown below.  I have shown in the comment for the `$to_loc_finalDT1` line, where I first see these two dirs:

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find path '\\T2\DisasterBackup\Loc_2019-03-08\Privileges\Privileges_HH_Bak.csv \\T2\DisasterBackup\Loc_2019-03-08\Privileges\Privileges_HH_Bak.csv' because it does not exist
```

So this is the pertinent powershell script:

```
$T2 = "\\T2\DisasterBackup\Loc" 
$toLocParentDT2 = CreateDatedFolder $parentDirBaseNameDT2 
$to_loc_finalDT2 = Join-Path -Path $toLocParentDT2 -ChildPath "Privileges" 
#create sub-folder location 
if(-Not (Test-Path $to_loc_finalDT2 )) 
{
   write-output  " Creating folder $to_loc_finalDT2 because it does not exist " 
   New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $to_loc_finalDT2 -force 
}


#second dir save files to
$parentDirBaseNameDT1 = "\\T1\DisasterBackup\Loc" 
$toLocParentDT1 = CreateDatedFolder $parentDirBaseNameDT1 
$to_loc_finalDT1 = Join-Path -Path $toLocParentDT1 -ChildPath "Privileges" #shows 2 dirs here in debugger: \\T2\DisasterBackup\Loc_2019-03-08\Privileges \\T2\DisasterBackup\Loc_2019-03-08\Privileges
#create sub-folder location 
if(-Not (Test-Path $to_loc_finalDT1 )) 
{
   write-output  " Creating folder $to_loc_finalDT1 because it does not exist " 
   New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $to_loc_finalDT1 -force 
}
```

I'm not sure how to get `Join-Path` to just have the one dir, as it should.  Right now, I think it's being treated as an array, which is not correct.

I tried searching for related issues, but didn't see anything similar.

***Update***

Here's the code for CreateDatedFolder:

```
#create dated folder to put backup files in 
function CreateDatedFolder([string]$name){
   $datedDir = ""
   $datedDir = "$name" + "_" + "$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"
   New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $datedDir -force
   return $datedDir
}
```

The output for that looks fine when it's returned.  It appends the date onto the \T2\DisasterBackup\Loc, but the debugger only shows one dir there, not an array or 2 dirs that are separate strings.

Comment: Is `CreateDatedFolder` a function? What does it do? To me it looks like `CreateDatedFolder` creates two outputs that are stored in `$toLocParentDT1` and `Join-Path` processes them both.

Comment: @T-Me - I added CreateDatedFolder to the Update of my question.  It appends the date to the folder given.  The output shows just one folder correctly, not the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [T-Me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10223991/t-me) correctly inferred before you posted the **`CreateDatedFolder`** source, the problem is that the function **inadvertently outputs *2* objects**, and `Join-Path` accepts an *array* of parent paths to each join with the child path.

Specifically, it is the `New-Item` call that accidentally creates an *additional* output object, just before your `return $datedDir` call.

`New-Item` outputs a `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instance representing the newly created directory and, due to **PowerShell's *implicit* output behavior**, that instance becomes part of what the function outputs *too* - **any command or expression inside a script / function that returns a value that isn't captured or redirected becomes part of the output**.

To prevent that, *suppress* the output:

```
$null = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $datedDir -force
```

Other ways to suppress output are discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375), which also discusses the *design rationale* for PowerShell's implicit output behavior.

Note that **you never *need* [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Return) in PowerShell in order to *output* a result** - but you may need it for *flow control*, to exit a function prematurely:

```
return $datedDir
```

is **syntactic sugar** for:

```
$datedDir # Implicitly output the value of $datedDir.
          # While you could also use `Write-Output $datedDir`,
          # that is rarely needed and actually slows things down.
return    # return from the function - flow control only
```

For more information about PowerShell's *implicit output* behavior, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375).