# Why does Range.BorderAround emit "True" to the console?

Tags: excel, powershell, output

Using BorderAround emits "True" to the console.

```
$range = $sum_wksht.Range('B{0}:G{0}' -f ($crow))
$range.BorderAround(1, -4138)
```

This can be overcome by using one of the following.

```
$wasted = $range.BorderAround(1, -4138)
[void]$range.BorderAround(1, -4138)
```

Why is this needed? Am I not creating the range correctly? Is there a better workaround?

Comment: according to what i can find on the MSDocs site, that method has a return object. i cannot find what it is ... but that `True` typically is a "this worked" success msg. one normally suppresses that with an assignment `$Null =`, casting to void `[void]$range.BorderAround(1, -4138)`, or by using `| Out-Null`. the 2nd is fastest, the 1st is the most common, the 3rd is much slower than the other two. the speed is not important unless you do it _frequently_, tho. [*grin*]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is this needed?

It is needed, because the [`BorderAround` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.borderaround) has a return value and, in PowerShell, **any command or expression that *outputs (returns) data*** is ***implicitly output* to the *(success) output stream***, which by default goes to the *host*, which is typically the *console window* (terminal) in which a PowerShell session runs.

That is, the data shows in the console/terminal, *unless* it is:

- captured (`$var = ...`)
- sent through the pipeline for further processing (`... | ...`;  the last pipeline segment's command may or may not produce output itself)
- redirected (`... >`)

or any combination thereof.

That is:

```bash
$range.BorderAround(1, -4138)
```

is (more efficient) shorthand for:

```bash
Write-Output $range.BorderAround(1, -4138)
```

(Explicit use of [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) is rarely needed.)

Since **you don't want that output, you must *suppress* it**, for which you have several options:

- `$null = ...`
- `[void] (...)`
- `... > $null`
- `... | Out-Null`

**`$null = ...` may be the best overall choice**, because:

- It conveys the intent to suppress *up front*

  - While `[void] = (...)` does that too, it often requires you to enclose an *expression* in `(...)` for syntactic reasons; e.g., `[void] 1 + 2` doesn't work as intended, only `[void] (1 + 2)`; similarly, a *command* must *always* be enclosed in `(...)`; `[void] New-Item test.txt` doesn't work, only `[void] (New-Item test.txt)` does.
- It performs well with both *command* output (e.g., `$null = Get-AdUser ...`) and *expression* output (e.g., `$null = $range.BorderAround(1, -4138)`).

Conversely, **avoid `... | Out-Null`**, because it is generally much slower (except in the edge case of a side effect-free expression's output in PowerShell (Core) 6+)<sup>[1]</sup>.

However, **if you need to silence *all* [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)** - not just the *success* output, but also errors, verbose output, ... -  you must **use `*> $null`**

---

#### Why does PowerShell produce output implicitly?

- As a *shell*, **PowerShell's output behavior is based on *streams***, as in traditional shells such as `cmd.exe` or Bash. (While traditional shells have *2* output streams - stdout and stderr - PowerShell has *6*, so as to provide more sophisticated functionality - see [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection).)

  - **A cmdlet, script, or function can write to the output streams as often as it wants, and such output is usually *instantly available* for display but notably also to potential consumers**, which **enables the streaming, one-by-one processing that the *pipeline* provides**.
  - This contrasts with traditional *programming languages*, whose output behavior is based on *return values*, typically provided via the `return` keyword, which conflates output data (the return value) with flow control (exit the scope and return to the caller).

    - A frequent pitfall is to expect PowerShell's `return` statement to act the same, but it doesn't: `return <val>` is just syntactic sugar for `<val>; return`, i.e., implicit output of `<val>` followed by an unconditional return of control to the caller; notably, the use of `return` does *not* preclude generation of output from earlier statements in the same scope.
- Unlike traditional shells, **PowerShell doesn't *require* an explicit write-to-the-output stream command in order to produce output**:

  - While PowerShell does have a counterpart to `echo`, namely [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output), its use is rarely needed.

    - Among the rare cases where `Write-Output` is useful is preventing enumeration of a collection on output with `-NoEnumerate`, or to use [common  parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) `-OutVariable` to both output data *and* capture it in a variable (however, note that *all* cmdlets as well as advanced functions / scripts themselves `-OutVariable`, so the use of `Write-Output` may not be needed). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76317309/45375) for more cases.
  - The **implicit output behavior**:

    - **is generally a *blessing***:

      - for interactive experimentation - just type any statement - notably including expressions such as `[IO.Path]::GetExtension('foo.txt')` and `[math]::Pow(2, 32)` - and see its output (akin to the behavior of a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)).
      - for writing concise code that doesn't need to spell out implied behavior (see example below).
    - can occasionally be a *pitfall*:

      - for users accustomed to the semantics of traditional programming languages.
      - due to the potential for accidental pollution of the output stream from statements that one doesn't expect to produce output, such as in your case; a more typical example is the `.Add()` method of the `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` class unexpectedly producing output.

Example:

```bash
# Define a function that takes an array of integers and
# outputs their hex representation (e.g., '0xa' for decimal 10)
function Get-HexNumber {
  param([int[]] $numbers)      
  foreach ($i in $numbers) {
    # Format the integer at hand 
    # *and implicitly output it*.
    '0x{0}' -f $i.ToString('x')
  }
}

# Call the function with integers 0 to 16 and loop over the
# results, sleeping 1 second between numbers.
Get-HexNumber (0..16) | ForEach-Object { "[$_]"; Start-Sleep 1 }
```

The above yields the following:

```bash
[0x0]
# 1-second pause
[0x1]
# 1-second pause
[0x2]
...
[0x10]
```

This demonstrates the streaming aspect of the behavior: `Get-HexNumber`'s output is available to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet call *as it is being produced*, not *after* `Get-HexNumber` has exited.

---

<sup>[1] In PowerShell (Core) 6+, `Out-Null` has an optimization if the only preceding pipeline segment is a *side effect-free expression* rather than a method or command call; e.g., `1..1e6 | Out-Null` executes in almost no time, because the expression is seemingly not even executed. However, such a scenario is atypical, and the functionally equivalent  `Write-Output (1..1e6) | Out-Null` takes a long time to run, much longer than `$null =  Write-Output (1..1e6)`.</sup>