# Why does a getter/setter property return duplicated value?

Tags: powershell, runspace

I'm playing around with creating and destroying runspaces. Everything seems to work as expected, but when I'm trying to access `Runspace.name` property I get duplicated name `someName someName`. Here's doc reference to this [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace.name?view=pscore-6.2.0)

**Expected output**

```
RUNSPACE Boobs CREATED
RUNSPACE Boobs DESTROYED
```

**Actual output**

```
RUNSPACE Boobs CREATED
RUNSPACE Boobs Boobs DESTROYED
```

**Code**

```
function main {
  $runspaceObject = createRunspace "Boobs"
  $output = destroyRunspace $runspaceObject
}
function createRunspace {
  param($name)
  $hash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
  $runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
  $runspace.Name = $name
  $runspace.Open()
  $runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('hash', $hash)
  $powershell = [powershell]::Create()
  $powershell.Runspace = $runspace
  $powershell.AddScript({
    return "RUNSPACE RETURN VALUE"
  })
  $runspaceObject = @{
    handle = $powershell.BeginInvoke()
    runspace = $runspace
    powershell = $powershell
    hash = $hash
  }
  Write-Host "RUNSPACE $name CREATED"
  return $runspaceObject
}

function destroyRunspace {
  param($runspaceObject)
  $output = $runspaceObject.powershell.EndInvoke($runspaceObject.handle)
  $runspaceObject.runspace.Close()
  $runspaceObject.powershell.Dispose()
  $name = $runspaceObject.runspace.name
  Write-Host "RUNSPACE $name DESTROYED"
  return $output
}

main
```

Comment: `$powershell.AddScript(…)` -> `$powershell.AddScript(…) | Out-Null`

Comment: @PetSerAl, just tested it, everything works, thank you sir!

Comment: @manidos, please see the linked question and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375 for background information.