# Problem in Powershell not consuming ReadKey

Tags: powershell, console.readkey, readkey

When using the following LOC in a custom Powershell function that essentially was a *"Wait until any key is pressed"* called from a script:

```
[System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
```

… later on, particularly when the function returned or completed its context I got:

```
KeyChar   Key Modifiers
-------   --- ---------
... Enter         0
```

Q: How to avoid this??

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution was that you need to consume the ReadKey call. i.e.:

```
  $keypress = [System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
```

I found the same with some other PowerShell calls, that did an action but returned a value, such as a count, that the returned value was eventually displayed. Yes I got unused warnings but I ignored them.

Hope this helps someone. It annoyed me for several days off an on until I realised this.

Comment: I hope the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) to the linked duplicate question explains why that is necessary, and how to simply _discard_ return values that aren't of interest.

Comment: The answer link above IS relevant,