# Prevent Powershell XML file updates from sending output to command line?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have this function I found online which updates an IIS web.config XML file based on values I am feeding it from CSV files. I would like to prevent the output of every XML entry modification from being printed when the function is executed. I have tried numerous times to place to utilize Out-Null but I cannot seem to locate which portion of this XML update function is causing the output.

I would like to remove all XML update output like shown below after the line "Setting web.config appSettings for D:\Inetpub\WWWRoot\test". The output seems to be the key/value pair the function is reading from the CSV file and updating the web.config file with.

> Setting web.config appSettings for D:\Inetpub\WWWRoot\test
> #text
> ----- allowFrame TRUE
>
> authenticationType SSO
>
> cacheProviderType Shared

Here is the function I am utilizing:

```
function Set-Webconfig-AppSettings
{
    param (
        # Physical path for the IIS Endpoint on the machine without the "web.config" part.
        # Example: 'D:\inetpub\wwwroot\cmweb510\'
        [parameter(mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String] $path,
 
        # web.config key that you want to create or change
        [parameter(mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String] $key,
 
        # Value of the key you want to create or change
        [parameter(mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String] $value
    )
 
   Write-Host "Setting web.config appSettings for $path" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
 
    $webconfig = Join-Path $path "web.config"
    [bool] $found = $false
 
    if (Test-Path $webconfig)
    {
        $xml = [xml](get-content $webconfig);
        $root = $xml.get_DocumentElement();
 
        foreach ($item in $root.appSettings.add)
        {
            if ($item.key -eq $key)
            {
                $item.value = $value;
                $found = $true;
            }
        }
 
        if (-not $found)
        {
            
            $newElement = $xml.CreateElement("add");
            $nameAtt1 = $xml.CreateAttribute("key")
            $nameAtt1.psbase.value = $key;
            $newElement.SetAttributeNode($nameAtt1);
 
            $nameAtt2 = $xml.CreateAttribute("value");
            $nameAtt2.psbase.value = $value;
            $newElement.SetAttributeNode($nameAtt2);
 
            $xml.configuration["appSettings"].AppendChild($newElement);
        }
        
        $xml.Save($webconfig)
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Error -Message "Error: File not found '$webconfig'"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both SetAttributeNode and AppendChild output information so we just need to `$null` or `[void]` those out

```
function Set-Webconfig-AppSettings
{
    param (
        # Physical path for the IIS Endpoint on the machine without the "web.config" part.
        # Example: 'D:\inetpub\wwwroot\cmweb510\'
        [parameter(mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String] $path,

        # web.config key that you want to create or change
        [parameter(mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String] $key,

        # Value of the key you want to create or change
        [parameter(mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String] $value
    )

   Write-Host "Setting web.config appSettings for $path" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan

    $webconfig = Join-Path $path "web.config"
    [bool] $found = $false

    if (Test-Path $webconfig)
    {
        $xml = [xml](get-content $webconfig);
        $root = $xml.get_DocumentElement();

        foreach ($item in $root.appSettings.add)
        {
            if ($item.key -eq $key)
            {
                $item.value = $value;
                $found = $true;
            }
        }

        if (-not $found)
        {
        
            $newElement = $xml.CreateElement("add");
            $nameAtt1 = $xml.CreateAttribute("key")
            $nameAtt1.psbase.value = $key;
            $null = $newElement.SetAttributeNode($nameAtt1);

            $nameAtt2 = $xml.CreateAttribute("value");
            $nameAtt2.psbase.value = $value;
            $null = $newElement.SetAttributeNode($nameAtt2);

            $null = $xml.configuration["appSettings"].AppendChild($newElement);
        }
    
        $xml.Save($webconfig)
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Error -Message "Error: File not found '$webconfig'"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell, **return values from .NET methods** (in general, all output) **that are neither assigned to a variable, nor sent through the pipeline to another command, nor redirected to a file
are *implicitly output* ("returned") from functions** - even without an explicit output command such as [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) or a `return` statement.
See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) for the rationale behind this implicit-output feature.

It follows that, in PowerShell:

- **When you call .NET methods, you need to be aware of whether or not they *return a value*** (technically, not returning a value is indicated by a return type of `void`).
- If they do and **if you don't need this return value**, you **must *explicitly discard (suppress) it***, so that it doesn't accidentally become part of the function's output.

In your case, it is the calls to the  [`System.Xml.XmlElement.SetAttributeNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement.SetAttributeNode) and [`System.Xml.XmlElement.AppendChild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement.AppendChild) methods that cause your problems, because they have return values that you're not suppressing.

[Doug Maurer's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65119278/45375) shows how you to discard these return values by **assigning the method calls to `$null` (`$null = ...`)**.

While two other **methods for suppressing output** exist as well - casting to `[void]` and piping to [`Out-Null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null) -  **`$null = ...`**
is the **best overall choice**, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375).