# Explain Powershell [void] behavior

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, void

My script exports some information from Sharepoint sites to a `.CSV` file.

```
# Enter Web Application URL
$WebAppURL="http://server"

# Enter Path to CSV-file
$CSVFilePath="Path"

$SiteCollections = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL | Get-SPSite -Limit All

$Tree = foreach ($Site in $SiteCollections) {
    foreach ($Web in $Site.AllWebs) {
    $Groups = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        foreach ($Group in $web.Groups) {
            [void]$Groups.Add($Group.Name)
        }

        $Groups = $Groups -join ','
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Url = $web.URL
            Title = $web.Title
            CountOfLists= $web.Lists.Count
            PermissionsInherited = $web.Permissions.Inherited
            Groups = $Groups
            }
    }
}

$Tree | Export-CSV $CSVFilePath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

If I use `[void]` before `$Groups.Add($Group.Name)` it works correctly, but without `[void]`, the script returns an empty `.CSV` file.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- PowerShell *implicitly* outputs values that are neither captured in a variable, suppressed (as with `[void] (...)`, `$null = ...`, or `Out-Null`), redirected (with `>` / `>>`), nor sent through the pipeline (`|`) to another command.

  - See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) for the design rationale behind this behavior.
- [`$Groups.Add($Group.Name)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList.Add) outputs an `[int]` ([`System.Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Int32)) value (the index of the newly appended element), so without the `[void]` cast this integer becomes part of first the inner and then the outer `foreach` loop's output<sup>[1]</sup>, and thereby effectively the *very first* output object captured in `$Tree`.
- When piping objects to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv), it is the *first* object alone that determines what columns to export, based on that object's (public) properties.
- An `[int]` instance is just a value itself, it doesn't have any *properties*, so the resulting CSV file is effectively empty.

---

<sup>[1] The generic equivalent of `System.Collections.ArrayList` is [`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1), whose `.Add()` method does *not* return a value, which is why its use is preferable in PowerShell (and generally). The equivalent construct call would be:

`$Groups = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[object]` or, in PSv5+,

`$Groups = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()`</sup>