# New-Item messing up my variable PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, variables, new-item

I wrote a very simple script to acquire a random free drive letter.
The function finds a random free letter , creates a new empty text file of that drive letter name eg. `Q.txt`
I then return the value as $new_letter but when it comes out of the function somehow newly file created path is a part of the variable  `C:\AppPack\Logs\Q.txt Q`

Is it something `New-Item` messing up with my `$new_letter` variable ?

```
function get_drive_letter()
{
$letter_acquired = $false
Do
{
$new_letter = Get-ChildItem function:[h-z]: -Name | ForEach-Object { if (!(Test-Path $_)){$_} } | random -Count 1 | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace ':$', ''}
    write-host ("RIGHT AFTER " + $new_letter)
    if (!(test-path "C:\AppPack\Logs\$new_letter.txt"))
    {    
    New-Item -Path C:\AppPack\Logs\ -Name "$new_letter.txt" -ItemType "file" 
    write-host ("FROM FUNCTION " + $new_letter)
    $letter_acquired = $true
    return $new_letter
     }
    
    
    else
    {
    write-host ("LETTER USED ALREADY")
    write-host ($new_letter)
    }
}
while($letter_acquired = $false)
}

$drive_letter = $null

$drive_letter = get_drive_letter
write-host ("RIGHT AFTER FUNCTION " + $drive_letter)
```

OUTPUT :

```
RIGHT AFTER Q
FROM FUNCTION Q
RIGHT AFTER FUNCTION C:\AppPack\Logs\Q.txt Q
```

Comment: The function returns all output from all commands run in the function.

Comment: @js2010 I have updated my Do- While as well , Cant I just return a single variable value ?

Comment: As an aside, `while($letter_acquired = $false)` is no different from `while($false)` - you'll want `while($letter_acquired -eq $false)` (I would prefer `while(-not $letter_acquired)`) for it to work the way you intend

Comment: You would have to hide the output of all other commands, for example `new-item file5 > $null`.  Return doesn't really do what you think it does.  It's only to branch out of code.

Comment: In short: any output - be it from a PowerShell command or a .NET method call - that is neither captured in a variable nor redirected (sent through the pipeline or to a file) is _implicitly output_. To simply _discard_ such output, use `$null = ...`.
If you don't discard such output, it becomes part of a script or function's "return value" (stream of output objects). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) to the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A PowerShell function outputs *everything*, not just the result of the expression right after `return`!

The additional file path you see is the output from `New-Item ...` - it returns a `FileInfo` object for the file you just created.

You can suppress output by assigning it to the special `$null` variable:

```
# Output from New-Item will no longer "bubble up" to the caller
$null = New-Item -Path C:\AppPack\Logs\ -Name "$new_letter.txt" -ItemType "file"
return $new_letter
```

Or by piping to `Out-Null`:

```
New-Item ... |Out-Null
```

Or by casting the entire pipeline to `[void]`:

```
[void](New-Item ...)
```

---

Although I recommend explicitly handling unwanted output at the call site, you *can* also work around this behavior with a *hoisting trick*.

To demonstrate, consider this dummy function - let's say we "inherit" it from a colleague who didn't always write the most intuitive code:

```
function Get-RandomSquare {
  "unwanted noise"

  $randomValue = 1..100 |Get-Random

  "more noise"

  $square = $randomValue * $randomValue

  return $square
}
```

The function above will output 3 objects - the two garbage strings one-by-one, followed by the result that we're actually interested in:

```
PS ~> $result = Get-RandomSquare
PS ~> $result
unwanted noise
more noise
6400
```

Let's say we've been told to make as few modifications as possible, but we *really* need to suppress the garbage output.

To do so, nest the entire function body in a new scriptblock literal, and then invoke the whole block using the dot-source operator (`.`) - this forces PowerShell to execute it in the function's *local* scope, meaning any variable assignments persist:

```
function Get-RandomSquare {
  # suppress all pipeline output
  $null = . {
    "unwanted noise"
    $randomValue = 1..100 |Get-Random 
    "more noise"
    $square = $randomValue

    return $square
  }

  # variables assigned in the block are still available
  return $square
}
```