# Why do I keep getting a list of properties when adding a node in powershell?

Tags: wpf, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm using powershell to update the Version node in a wpf csproj file. Everytime I add the version node (never understood I have to when it's already there), suddenly a list of properties appear.

```
# My Wpf App
Write-Host "WpfApp Versioning started"

$sourceDir = "C:\Users\me\source\repos\mysolution"

$csprojfilename = $sourceDir +"\myapp\myapp.csproj"
"Project file to update " + $csprojfilename

[xml]$csprojcontents = Get-Content -Path $csprojfilename;

"Current version number is " + $csprojcontents.Project.PropertyGroup.Version + "."
$oldversionNumber = $csprojcontents.Project.PropertyGroup.Version

# https://gist.github.com/bcnzer/f8d50699c5bf7614923bff733662cb1a
if ($csprojcontents.Project.PropertyGroup.name -notmatch "Version") 
{ 
    Write-Host "Version is null."
    $csprojcontents.Project.PropertyGroup.AppendChild($csprojcontents.ImportNode(([xml]"<Version/>").DocumentElement,$true)) 
}

Write-Host "Update Version."
$csprojcontents.SelectNodes("/Project/PropertyGroup/Version")[0].InnerText = [version]($ecatBuildNumber)

Write-Host "Save csproj."
$csprojcontents.Save($csprojfilename)

"Version number has been updated from " + $oldversionNumber + " to " + $ecatBuildNumber + "."

Write-Host "WpfApp Versioning Finished"
```

This is the output I get when using Powershell ISE.

> WpfApp Versioning started
>
> Project file to update
> C:\Users\me\source\repos\mysolution\myapp\myapp.csproj
> Current version number is 6.0.0.6                                   .
> Version is null.
>
> Name            : Version LocalName       : Version NamespaceURI    :
> Prefix          :  NodeType        : Element ParentNode      :
> PropertyGroup OwnerDocument   : #document IsEmpty         : True
> Attributes      : {} HasAttributes   : False SchemaInfo      :
> System.Xml.XmlName InnerXml        :  InnerText       :  NextSibling
> :  PreviousSibling : Version Value           :  ChildNodes      : {}
> FirstChild      :  LastChild       :  HasChildNodes   : False
> IsReadOnly      : False OuterXml        :  BaseURI
> :  PreviousText    :
>
> Name            : Version LocalName       : Version NamespaceURI    :
> Prefix          :  NodeType        : Element ParentNode      :
> PropertyGroup OwnerDocument   : #document IsEmpty         : True
> Attributes      : {} HasAttributes   : False SchemaInfo      :
> System.Xml.XmlName InnerXml        :  InnerText       :  NextSibling
> :  PreviousSibling : Version Value           :  ChildNodes      : {}
> FirstChild      :  LastChild       :  HasChildNodes   : False
> IsReadOnly      : False OuterXml        :  BaseURI
> :  PreviousText    :
>
> Name            : Version LocalName       : Version NamespaceURI    :
> Prefix          :  NodeType        : Element ParentNode      :
> PropertyGroup OwnerDocument   : #document IsEmpty         : True
> Attributes      : {} HasAttributes   : False SchemaInfo      :
> System.Xml.XmlName InnerXml        :  InnerText       :  NextSibling
> :  PreviousSibling : Version Value           :  ChildNodes      : {}
> FirstChild      :  LastChild       :  HasChildNodes   : False
> IsReadOnly      : False OuterXml        :  BaseURI
> :  PreviousText    :
>
> Name            : Version LocalName       : Version NamespaceURI    :
> Prefix          :  NodeType        : Element ParentNode      :
> PropertyGroup OwnerDocument   : #document IsEmpty         : True
> Attributes      : {} HasAttributes   : False SchemaInfo      :
> System.Xml.XmlName InnerXml        :  InnerText       :  NextSibling
> :  PreviousSibling : Version Value           :  ChildNodes      : {}
> FirstChild      :  LastChild       :  HasChildNodes   : False
> IsReadOnly      : False OuterXml        :  BaseURI
> :  PreviousText    :
>
> Name            : Version LocalName       : Version NamespaceURI    :
> Prefix          :  NodeType        : Element ParentNode      :
> PropertyGroup OwnerDocument   : #document IsEmpty         : True
> Attributes      : {} HasAttributes   : False SchemaInfo      :
> System.Xml.XmlName InnerXml        :  InnerText       :  NextSibling
> :  PreviousSibling : Version Value           :  ChildNodes      : {}
> FirstChild      :  LastChild       :  HasChildNodes   : False
> IsReadOnly      : False OuterXml        :  BaseURI
> :  PreviousText    :
>
> Name            : Version LocalName       : Version NamespaceURI    :
> Prefix          :  NodeType        : Element ParentNode      :
> PropertyGroup OwnerDocument   : #document IsEmpty         : True
> Attributes      : {} HasAttributes   : False SchemaInfo      :
> System.Xml.XmlName InnerXml        :  InnerText       :  NextSibling
> :  PreviousSibling : Version Value           :  ChildNodes      : {}
> FirstChild      :  LastChild       :  HasChildNodes   : False
> IsReadOnly      : False OuterXml        :  BaseURI
> :  PreviousText    :
>
> Update Version. Save csproj. Version number has been updated from
> 6.0.0.6                                    to 6.0.0.6.
>
> WpfApp Versioning Finished

It's strange. How do I get it to stop doing that?

Comment: In short: any output - be it from a PowerShell command or a .NET method call - that is neither captured in a variable nor redirected (sent through the pipeline or to a file) is _implicitly output_ from a script or function. To simply _discard_ such output, use `$null = ...`.
If you don't discard such output, it becomes part of a script or function's "return value" (stream of output objects). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) to the linked duplicate.

Comment: Specifically, it is the [`.AppendChild()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild#System_Xml_XmlNode_AppendChild_System_Xml_XmlNode_) method call that produces implicit output in your case.

Comment: @mklement0 That linked answer did help explain what was going on and the why the solutions worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @OnTheNetAgain; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to your great logging, it is easy to isolate the error.  Check your syntax on this line:

```
# https://gist.github.com/bcnzer/f8d50699c5bf7614923bff733662cb1a
if ($csprojcontents.Project.PropertyGroup.name -notmatch "Version") 
{ 
    Write-Host "Version is null."
    #this line below
    $csprojcontents.Project.PropertyGroup.AppendChild($csprojcontents.ImportNode(([xml]"<Version/>").DocumentElement,$true)) 
}
```

The syntax for importing a new node is pretty different than I've usually seen.  I changed the syntax like this and it worked.

```
if ($csprojcontents.Project.PropertyGroup.name -notmatch "Version") 
{ 
    Write-Host "Version is null."
    $child = $csprojcontents.CreateElement("Version")
    $csprojcontents.Project.PropertyGroup.AppendChild($child) 
}
```

As for why you need to do this, this code first adds a Version node to make sure its there, and then tries to set the version to the right value.

Comment: Make that `$null = $csprojcontents.Project.PropertyGroup.AppendChild($child) ` and that works exactly as expected. Thanks.