How does a string unexpectedly become an array?
In one of my script I have the following problem: assigning to a string variable the result of a function makes the string an array. Example:
---------- (function edited for clarity)
$x=""
Function extrMail{param([string]$pFullAddr)
    [string]$wAddr = ""
    $regex = ".. omitted for brevity, check for valid mail address..."
    $pFullAddr -match $regex | Out-Null
    $wAddr = $Matches.values
    if ($wAddr -notlike "@") {
        $wAddr = "$wAddr@undef.it"
    }
    return [string]$wAddr 
}    

...
$x= extrMail "xy"


----------

but if I look at it it's 


$x=1
abcd
$x.Count # is 2

I've made several runs, in step mode to try and find where the problem arise, but no way...
I can't understand why...
Thanks for any help
PS: I'm a seasoned system engineer, I know various programming languages but I'm really a newbie with Powershell...


Your question needs a clear example that replicates the issue, otherwise answer will be based on pure guessing. Update your question providing a minimal reproducible example.

Thx for suggestion, but the problem really is that simple, a small function which produce a STRING but the variable receiving it becomes an array. I've checked for duplicated names (frequent error, where same name defined as both a string and an array...) Stepping thru the function until last instruction which is "return $result" in debug mode £result IS a string, but the immediately following step, the assignment to the other variable ($x in my example) result in an array, debug show it as 2 lines.

your function as you have it in your question is not returning anything and we don't know what "... some code here" is.

A common cause of functions unexpectedly returning more than intended (with two or more output objects becoming an array when the output is collected) is PowerShell's implicit output behavior - see this answer.

And: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74717663/1701026

First of all, thank you for your quick answers.
Actually the function is the following:
Function extrMail{param([string]$pFullAddr)
[string]$wAddr = ""
$regex = ".. omitted for brevity..."
$pFullAddr -match $regex | Out-Null
$wAddr = $Matches.values
if ($wAddr -notlike "@") {
$wAddr = "$wAddr@undef.it"
}
return [string]$wAddr
}
Input is string that can contain a complete or incomplete email address, for example "name" mailx@dom.com where only
the real address must be returned, text between < an >.

Sorry for formatting... it's my first question here...

I've added \ tho show where lines divide...

Please edit the original post, not write it in the comments. Otherwise people are not likely going to read it.(and comments don't format well either)

Thx for suggestion, done...
