# Looking to suppress "COM Interop is not supported on this platform" error in Exchange Online Script

Tags: macos, powershell, error-handling, scripting, office365

I've been working on a script to remove mobile devices from Exchange Online. Everything else works fine except this one bit:

```
foreach ($item in $userdevices) {
  Remove-MobileDevice -Identity $item -whatif
  [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($item) | Out-Null 
}
```

This line `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($item) | Out-Null` is required for the script not to hang, but it outputs the error due to incompatibility with Mac.

The error I receive is:

```
MethodInvocationException: /Users/XXX/XXX/MDM.ps1:80:17
Line |
  80 |  …             [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObjec …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "ReleaseComObject" with "1" argument(s): "COM Interop is not supported on this platform."
```

I have tried adding in `try`-`catch` mechanisms, `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, `-WarningAction SilentlyContinue`, and a few other variations with no luck. I get this error:

```
ParserError: /Users/XXX/XXX/MDM.ps1:80:83
Line |
  80 |  … nteropservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($item) -ErrorAction:Silentl …
     |                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unexpected token '-ErrorAction' in expression or statement.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($item)` is an *expression* (a .NET method call)**, and in order to **silence an *exception*** (aka *statement-terminating error*) it may throw, **you need [`try { ... } catch { ... }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally)**:

```bash
# Using just {} as the catch block means that any exception is *quietly ignored*.
try { 
  $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($item) 
} catch {}
```

<sup>Note: `$null = ...` is a typically better-performing alternative to `... | Out-Null` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) for details.</sup>

Note:

- If needed, the exception object is available via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) inside the `catch` block; you an *re-throw* the exception simply with `throw` (no argument needed).
- Even if you simply *ignore* the exception, it is still recorded in PowerShell's session-wide error log, the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> ```bash
> [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($item) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
> ```

This causes a syntax error, because the [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction) (like all [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters), i.e. `-WarningAction` too) only apply to *commands*, more specifically, to *cmdlets* (e.g., `Get-ChildItem`) and *[advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) functions and scripts* (which behave like cmdlets, but, unlike the former, which are implemented via *compiled code* (.NET assemblies), are written *in PowerShell*).

Note that expressions and commands are each parsed according to *separate syntax rules* aka *parsing modes*, discussed in the conceptual [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing) help topic.